# Whether the storm supervisor works independently without zookeeper and nimbus

Tags: apache-storm

I am very new to Apache Storm and am trying to set up a multi node cluster. My zookeeper and Nimbus run on one machine and the supervisors are running on another machine. During the configuration stage, I will submit the topology to my supervisors. Supervisors have 1 spout and 1 bolt.

In my cluster set up,there are chances that the connectivity between the machines may get lost for sometime. So, will my supervisors work independently even after it lost the connectivity to the nimbus/zookeeper?

Regards,
Remya

Answer (score 2):

If a supervisor looses connection to Zookeeper, the supervisor and it's worker processes die. To prevent this, set up Zookeeper in a reliable fashion, i.e., multi-node deployment.

See "Set up a Zookeeper cluster" here: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html

Also have a look into Storm tutorial: https://storm.apache.org/tutorial.html